# Amazon RDS vs local database

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine, amazon-rds

I'm currently working on a multiplayer game made in Unity and I need to set a database to store my questions. The game will have a thousand question approximately, and it may grow later on. I was wondering if I should consider using Amazon RDS to store the questions and that each player retrieve the question from there, or if I should store a db file on the app for players to access locally.

What would be more convenient and why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1000 pieces of data is not very big. If we assume 1KB of text, then the total size would be **1MB**. This can comfortably fit in memory and does not need a database.

Text compresses quite nicely, so the download file could be **zipped** and it would be even smaller.

You could consider **storing the question file in Amazon S3** and have the game securely download the file when the game starts. It would then have all the data locally and would not need to connect to a database for the questions.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give Amazon S3 a look!